# Grunt Server connect proxy getting 504 after a POST

Tags: gruntjs

Having a bit of a problem with Grunt server using proxies.

I have everything working fine, however, when I submit a post request I get a 200 success from my proxy.

Then with each subsequent use of that proxy I get a 504 Gateway Timeout.

For instance if I post to student-minors proxy it goes through fine.
Every time after that I get a 504 when I try to do something else with that proxy.

I can use the other proxies with a get, I can get terms and courses.

Seems like something is either hanging, throwing an error of some kind, but I can't see it.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the connect server with the proxy stuff

```html
 // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
            rules: [
                        {from: '^/poc-proxy/(.*)$', to: '/authorizations/$1'},
                        {from: '^/service/apis/terms/(.*)$', to: '/terms/$1'},
                        {from: '^/service/apis/courses/(.*)$', to: '/courses/$1'},
                        {from: '^/service/apis/studentMinors/(.*)$', to: '/studentMinors/$1'}
                    ],
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                base: 'dev',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                middleware: function (connect, res,options, middlewares) {
                    return [
                    rewriteRules,
                    serveStatic('./dev'),
                    require('grunt-middleware-proxy/lib/Utils').getProxyMiddleware()
                  ]
                }
            },
            proxies: [{
                    context: '/authorizations', //REQUIRED! Must start with a '/' should not end with a '/'
                    host: 'authorizations.com', //REQUIRED! Should not contain 'http://' or 'https://'
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    https: true,//Optional, defaults to false
                    headers: {//Optional.
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    }
                  },
                  {
                  context: '/terms', //REQUIRED! Must start with a '/' should not end with a '/'
                  host: 'terms.com', //REQUIRED! Should not contain 'http://' or 'https://'
                  changeOrigin: true,
                  https: true,//Optional, defaults to false
                  headers: {//Optional.
                      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                  }
                },
                {
                    context: '/courses', //REQUIRED! Must start with a '/' should not end with a '/'
                    host: 'courses.com', //REQUIRED! Should not contain 'http://' or 'https://'
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    https: true,//Optional, defaults to false
                    headers: {//Optional.
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    }
                },
                {
                    context: '/studentMinors', //REQUIRED! Must start with a '/' should not end with a '/'
                    host: 'minors.com', //REQUIRED! Should not contain 'http://' or 'https://'
                    https: true,
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    headers: {//Optional.
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    }
                  }
              ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: We switched to use grunt-connect-proxy, but we still had a problem with the latest version.

Comment: We forced grunt-connect-proxy to always use 0.1.10 in the package.json and that seems to have fixed it for us.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the server options.

```
    server: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            base: 'dev',
            hostname: 'localhost',
            middleware: function (connect, res,options, middlewares) {
                return [
                          rewriteRules,
                          serveStatic('./dev'),
                          //require('grunt-middleware-proxy/lib/Utils').getProxyMiddleware()
                          require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest
                       ]
            }
        },
```

Changed the task run

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app', function (target) {

  if (target === 'dist') {
    return grunt.task.run(['build', 'browserSync:dist']);
  }

  grunt.task.run([
    'configureRewriteRules',
    //'setupProxies:server',
    'configureProxies:server',
    'connect:server',
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:server',
    'postcss:dev',
    'copy:dev',
    //'browserSync:livereload', //Browsersync a proxy servers conflict with CORS
    'watch'
  ]);
});
```